# Pandas - show percentage of values in one column, grouped by other column

Tags: python, pandas, percentage

So I have a Pandas DataFrame with two columns:
first is Grade with values 0 to 9
second is Criteria, with values 0 or 1.

Grade (0-9/ Criteria(0/1)

```
   Grade  Criteria
0      0         1
1      1         0
2      2         1
3      2         0
4      5         1
5      2         1
```

etc

I need to count "Criteria rate", which is actually sum of "1"s in Criteria column, divided by appropriate number of rows in Criteria column, but grouped by Grade column values.
For example, for Grade = 2 we  count sum of 1 in Criteria column and divide it by number of rows with Grade 2: 2/3, so for Grade 2 we get 0.66 approx.
In my example, the answer should look like:

Grade / Criteria rate

```
   Grade  Criteria
0      0  1.000000
1      1  0.000000
2      2  0.666667
3      5  1.000000
```

Any ideas, how to do this?
Also the add. question - how to do this, if we have "yes/no" text values in Criteria column?
I've searched here, but found only solutions to groupby's, divided by total rows count etc.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can aggregate `sum` with `size` and then divide columns:

```
df = df.groupby('Grade')['Criteria'].agg(['sum','size'])
df['new'] = df['sum'] / df['size']
print (df)
       sum  size       new
Grade                     
0        1     1  1.000000
1        0     1  0.000000
2        2     3  0.666667
5        1     1  1.000000
```

Or use custom function:

```
#not exclude NaNs 
df = df.groupby('Grade')['Criteria'].agg(lambda x: x.sum() / len(x)).reset_index(name='new')

#exclude possible NaNs
df = df.groupby('Grade')['Criteria'].agg(lambda x: x.sum() / x.count()).reset_index(name='new')
```

For `yes/no` values working with boolean mask - `True`s are processes like `1`s:

```
print (df)
   Grade Criteria
0      0      yes
1      1       no
2      2      yes
3      2       no
4      5      yes
5      2      yes

df = (df['Criteria'] == 'yes').groupby(df['Grade']).agg(lambda x: x.sum() / len(x)).reset_index(name='new')
print (df)
   Grade       new
0      0  1.000000
1      1  0.000000
2      2  0.666667
3      5  1.000000
```

Answer (score 3):

If criteria is `1` or `0`, or even `True` or `False`

You can use `mean`

#### `groupby`

```
df.groupby('Grade').mean()

       Criteria
Grade          
0      1.000000
1      0.000000
2      0.666667
5      1.000000
```

---

#### `set_index` and `mean`

```
df.set_index('Grade').mean(level=0)

       Criteria
Grade          
0      1.000000
1      0.000000
2      0.666667
5      1.000000
```

---

In the case that `'Criteria'` are `'yes'` and `'no'` strings

```
df

   Grade Criteria
0      0      yes
1      1       no
2      2      yes
3      2       no
4      5      yes
5      2      yes
```

You can group the boolean evaluation

```
df.Criteria.eq('yes').groupby(df.Grade).mean()

Grade
0    1.000000
1    0.000000
2    0.666667
5    1.000000
Name: Criteria, dtype: float64
```

---

Use `reset_index` on any of these answers to get the desired dataframe

Comment: and add answer for yes and no values.